# Cancan with current_user in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I set up my Abilities, and on top of my Controller i have the authorize resource from Can Can

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

My Controller action's where written with the current_user method e.g.:

```
def new
  @question = current_user.questions.new
end

def edit
  @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
end
```

With cancan this seems not to be working.

How do i get this working properly ?

Comment: Define `seems not to be working`. I have hundreds of controllers doing similar things.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Couldn't find Question with id=11 [WHERE "questions"."user_id" = ?]

Comment: Basically the question.user_id don't matches the current_user.user_id

Comment: Yes yes, ofc. The problem is that an "Admin" user can not edit question's he did not create..

Comment: Post your controller and more information. It's really hard to assist with minimal information. Chances are, your `user_id` field is nil.

Comment: What defines an admin user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, this would be the expected behavior.

Try modifying your edit action to

```
def edit
  if current_user.role_id == 4
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  else
    @question = current_user.questions.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```